# How to load adal.js in webpack inside Angular 2 (Azure-AD)

Tags: angular, webpack, azure-active-directory, adal, adal.js

Inside my NG2 project, if I write:

```
import adal from 'adal-angular';
```

it gives me 'adal is undefined'.  Why is that?

I want to use adal.js inside my angular 2 project. 
I already have run

```
npm install adal-angular --save
npm install @types/adal --save
```

Then, inside my component.ts file, if I do:

import adal from 'adal-angular';

adal is undefined.

**How can I import it correctly inside my component.ts file, and also use the typings**?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To fix this, you will need to do a number of things:

```
npm install adal-angular --save        (=>"@types/adal": "^1.0.22")
npm install @types/adal --save-dev     (=>"adal-angular": "^1.0.12")
npm install expose-loader
```

With those packages installed, you have to do the following: 
inside your component.ts:

1. write a triple slash to import the typings
   `/// <reference path="../../../node_modules/@types/adal/index.d.ts" />`
2. import adal.js and expose it as AuthenticationContext using the expose loader
   `import 'expose?AuthenticationContext!../../../node_modules/adal-angular/lib/adal.js';`
3. declare a variable of type AuthenticationContextStatic and assign it value of AuthenticationContext
   `let createAuthContextFn: adal.AuthenticationContextStatic = AuthenticationContext;`
4. Now you can initialize the authentication context using the createAuthContextFn
   **`let config: adal.Config = {  clientId : 'test' };
   let context = new createAuthContextFn(config);`**
5. (Optionally) To handle the callback from AD, write this piece of code inside your bootstrapped component aka AppComponent:
   `if (context.isCallback(location.hash)) {
      var requestInfo = context.getRequestInfo(location.hash);
      context.saveTokenFromHash(requestInfo);
   }`

Comment: Can you provide a plunkr of this? I am unable to get past the let part as I get errors on step 5

Comment: Here is a gist [auth.provider.ts](https://gist.github.com/HNeukermans/b282bb6779c91e7b1c98caca24a2c5b4)

Comment: you can clone [Ng2a.Frontend](https://github.com/HNeukermans/Ng2a.Frontend). To get a working example

Comment: I just took a look at that repo. I get an error trying to run the server using the quickstart :/

Comment: also, in that auth.provider.ts, what is AuthContext?

Comment: if you use typescript and want to use adal, you can also try using npm install adal-ts.

Comment: @hannesneukermans Thanks for the help here.  Can you post a gist of your authentication.context.ts file, too?

Answer (score 2):

you can also use adal-ts

> npm install adal-ts --save