# 401 Calling Authorized WebApi Endpoint

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, owin, azure-active-directory

I have an Angular 2 App that I am Authenticating against Azure AD and then making a call to a developed WebApi to get additional information.

I first change the window location to the Azure Login Page for SSO

```
window.location.href =  "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + 
        this.tenantId + 
        "/oauth2/authorize?" +
        "response_type=id_token+token&" +
        "response_mode=fragment&" +
        "client_id=" + this.clientId + "&" +
        "redirect_uri=" + encodeURIComponent(window.location.href) + "/&" +
        "scope=openid&" +
        "state=" + this.state + "&" +
        "nonce=" + this.nonce;
```

I then get the access_token param from the hash and pass it to a service that calls my Api

Call from Angular 2 to WebApi

```
    public testApi(token): Observable<any> {
    let headers = new Headers({
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token, 'Accept': 'application/json; odata.metadata=minimal' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.httpService.get('/api/values', options)
        .map((response: Response) => response.json());
}
```

This call comes back with a 401 with this message

> Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid"

After looking around, I thought it may be with how I am setting up OWIN on my Api side, but after reading MSFT documentation, it should be like so

Configure Section in Statup.cs

```
   app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
        {
            Authority = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:AADInstance"] + Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:TenantId"],
            Audience = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:Audience"]
        });
```

appsettings.json

```
  "Authentication": {
     "AzureAd": {
       "AADInstance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
       "Audience": "https://isaaclevin.com/testlogin",
       "ClientId": "26931518-d4e2-4ad7-bc78-64857754bbf3",
       "Domain": "isaaclevin.com",
       "TenantId": "3335f25c-177f-424d-96cc-5a5a3d1798cd"
    }
```

And finally the simple Api with the Authorize Attribute

```
    [Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

Not quite sure what I am doing wrong here, but it is an auth issue for sure. If I take the [Authorize] attribute off, the api call works (but that is obvious). I am validating the token on the client side and it is working just fine.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this issue after you retry get the new access token to call you web API again? And to narrow down this issue, I also suggest that you capture the **access token** using **fiddler**, and you can verify the token using the code from [here](https://github.com/dream-365/OfficeDev-Samples/blob/master/samples/Office365DevQuickStart/OAuth2-basic/JsonWebTokenValidator.cs).

Answer (score 0):

To fix this I had to add the resource to the login call. I am getting an issue now with continual request for.consent, but I can hot the api fine

Comment: Even I'm facing a similar issue now. What exactly did you do to solve problem ?

Comment: i useda library wrapper for adal.js https://github.com/sureshchahal/angular2-adal

Comment: I tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40044892/how-to-load-adal-js-in-webpack-inside-angular-2-azure-ad  example. It don't work for me.

Comment: Just wondering if you have any github example for your project.

Comment: he has an example solution on git, take a look

Comment: Can you further explain what exactly did you to mean by "Add the resource to the login call". Thanks!